# How to know if it is the correct address and calldata when holders call the propose function?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin-contracts, dao

The propose function in the governance contract from OZ can receive any random address and calldata.

When the proposal is executed with the execution function in timeLockcontroller from OZ, the transaction will be failed.

I am wondering if there is prevention from this failure ?